Django collecstatic requires STATIC_ROOT but setting STATIC_ROOT blocks upload to S3
So I use S3 static storage in combination with Django to serve static files for a Zappa deploy. This all worked quite well for a long time until I recently upgraded to a new Django version.
Python 3.12.3
Django 5.1.1

It used to be, I could use:
python manage.py collectstatic
To push my static files over to my S3 bucket. But, currently, that fails with this error:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.

However, If I set a STATIC_ROOT, then instead of pushing to S3, it collects the static files locally.
You have requested to collect static files at the destination
location as specified in your settings:

    /-local storage-/static

This is my settings.py:
# STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

YOUR_S3_BUCKET = "static-bucket"

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC = YOUR_S3_BUCKET

# These next two lines will serve the static files directly
# from the s3 bucket
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % YOUR_S3_BUCKET
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

The credentials and all are also in settings.py. It seems I a missing something, I need STATIC_ROOT to run collectstatic, but having STATIC_ROOT makes static collection be local.
Edit: Fixed the question, STATIC_ROOT was defined twice. Didn't change behavior unfortunately.
Edit: added information
STORAGES is not set it seems.
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
But my Django version is 5.1.1
I am using the django_s3_storage package yes, django_s3_storage and storages are both installed apps.
Solution:
STATICFILES_STORAGE has been deprecated since 4.2 and removed in 5.1
Correct config becomes this:
# These next two lines will serve the static files directly
# from the s3 bucket
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % YOUR_S3_BUCKET
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN

STORAGES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage',
    },
    'staticfiles': {
        'BACKEND': 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'bucket_name': AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME_STATIC,
        },
    },
}

Thank you @abdul-aziz-barkat

why is STATIC_URL defined twice?

Sloppy formatting on my part, that should not be there. I'll fix the question,

Not sure if this helps, but Django did change things that affect AWS storage.  Check this: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html#configuration-settings

Are you using the django_s3_storage package? Are you sure it works with recent versions of Django? People usually use django-storages for static and media files.

What's the value of your STORAGES setting (or the STATICFILES_STORAGE setting in case your version of Django is less than 4.2)?

STORAGES is not set it seems.
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django_s3_storage.storage.StaticS3Storage"
But my Django version is 5.1.1
I am using the django_s3_storage package yes, django_s3_storage and storages are both installed apps.

@Eloque STATICFILES_STORAGE has been deprecated since 4.2 and removed in 5.1, you need to use the STORAGES setting instead as described by the duplicate target.
